# Ionic + Firebase - Push notifications

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have a ionic + firebase chat app and I'd like to send a notification to a user when a new message is received.

In the Ionic oficial documentation, the recommended plugin for this is:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

But as you can see inside the repository, it hasnt been updated since last february and based in comments inside it, it seems like it doesnt work with last Android OS versions.

Does anyone know an alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem to implement push notifications in my app last month. This is the best tutorial to do that: https://medium.com/@senning/push-notifications-with-ionic-and-cordova-plugin-firebase-ab0c0cad3cc0

I customized this tutorial to a file: **messaging.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from './api.service';
import {AppApiResponse} from '../interfaces/interfaces'
import {Firebase} from "@ionic-native/firebase";
import {Platform} from "ionic-angular";
import {AngularFirestore} from "@angular/fire/firestore";

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {

  private userUid: string;

  constructor(private firebase: Firebase,
              public afs: AngularFirestore,
              public platform: Platform) {
  }

  initializeFirebase(userUid) {
    this.userUid = userUid;
    if (!this.platform.is("core")) {
      this.firebase.subscribe("all");
      this.platform.is('android') ? this.initializeFirebaseAndroid() : this.initializeFirebaseIOS();
    }
  }

  initializeFirebaseAndroid() {
    this.firebase.getToken().then(token => {
      this.saveTokenToFirestore(token);
      console.log('token android= ' + JSON.stringify(token));
    });
    this.firebase.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
      this.saveTokenToFirestore(token);
      console.log('token refresh android= ' + JSON.stringify(token));
    });
    this.subscribeToPushNotifications();
  }

  initializeFirebaseIOS() {
    this.firebase.grantPermission()
      .then(() => {
        this.firebase.getToken().then(token => {
          this.saveTokenToFirestore(token);
          console.log('token ios= ' + JSON.stringify(token));
        });
        this.firebase.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
          this.saveTokenToFirestore(token);
          console.log('token refresh ios= ' + JSON.stringify(token));
        });
        this.subscribeToPushNotifications();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.firebase.logError('push erro ios= ' + error);
      });
  }

  subscribeToPushNotifications() {
    this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('response push= ' + JSON.stringify(response));
      if (response.tap) {
        //Received while app in background (this should be the callback when a system notification is tapped)
        //This is empty for our app since we just needed the notification to open the app
      } else {
        //received while app in foreground (show a toast)
      }
    });
  }

  private saveTokenToFirestore(token) {
    if (!token) return;

    const devicesRef = this.afs.collection('devices');

    const docData = {
      token,
      userId: this.userUid,
    };

    return devicesRef.doc(token).set(docData)
  }
}
```

To use in your code is just include to page **constructor**:

```
public msgService: MessagingService
```

And use:

```
try {
    this.msgService.initializeFirebase(user.uid);
} catch (error) {
    console.log('fire push erro= ' + error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try tomorrow. Does it work with the last IOS OS version?

Comment: Based on your code and the one in the tutorial, that you subscribe to notifications and then the device is ready to show them if you create a notification in google FCM, but, how can you create one inside the project when the user send a new chat message?