# FCM notification click action in ionic and angular fire messaging

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm using Ionic 4 and [AngularFire2 Messaging](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/messaging/messaging.md) for Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications.

I'm trying to tell FCM what to do when the notification is clicked (or tapped) by the user. 
That should be done by the **click_action for android and link for web push properties. 
I am not sure what to provide here for an Ionic app however?**

Also it would be nice if I could set the time for how long a web push notification is visible on desktop, but I don't think there is an option for that.

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the end result? Have you reviewed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741747/ionic-firebase-push-notifications ?

Comment: @bergben are you allowed to use any third party plugins?

Comment: yes @Webruster! The expected end result is a way to tell what should happen when the user clicks a notification. Like 'OPEN_HOME' in the click_action should be then caught somewhere in the ionic loop and I can handle it and open the home page through the router @Henry

Comment: @bergben then i have been using [onesignal](https://onesignal.com/) , it solves the wat ever scenario you are explaining and integration is easy

Comment: @Webruster I'd like to use FCM though, that's what the question is all about

Comment: @bergben yes, i do understand and using FCM you can configure it , have you looked into it?

Comment: Hi @bergben, did you ever found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Casadiego